# using jquery show/hide doesn't keep css in div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that creates a border with css and what I want to do is show a form when a user clicks the button.

HTML form:

```
<div class="dropshadow-add">
    <h3>Add</h3>
        <button class="addwebcam">Add</button>
        <button class="addaxiscam">Add Another</button>

    <div id="cameraformwebcam" title="Add a webcam">
    <form id='AddCameraFormWebcam' name='' method='post' action=''>
        <label for="CameraName">Camera name:&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="CameraName" name="camera_name" size="24" maxlength="36" value="Enter label for camera" />
        <label for='CameraQuality'>Camera quality:&nbsp;</label>
        <select id='CameraQuality' name='camera_quality'>
            <option value='HIGH' selected='selected'>High</option>
            <option value='MEDIUM'>Medium</option>
            <option value='MOBILE'>Mobile</option>
        </select>
...
        <button type='submit' class='submit_camera' name='addcamera' value='Add'>Add</button>
        <button type='button' class='cancel_changes' name='cancel_changes' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
    </form>
    </div>
<div id="cameraformaxis" title="Add an Axis camera">
    <form id='AddCameraFormAxis' name='' method='post' action=''>
        <label for="CameraName">Camera name:&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="CameraName" name="camera_name" size="24" maxlength="36" value="Enter label for camera" />
        <label for='CameraQuality'>Camera quality:&nbsp;</label>
        <select id='CameraQuality' name='camera_quality'>
            <option value='HIGH' selected='selected'>High</option>
            <option value='MEDIUM'>Medium</option>
            <option value='MOBILE'>Mobile</option>
        </select>
...
        <button type='submit' class='submit_camera' name='addcamera' value='Add'>Add</button>
        <button type='button' class='cancel_changes' name='cancel_changes' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery code to show/hide the form on click:

```
jQuery('#cameraformwebcam').hide();
jQuery('#cameraformaxis').hide();

jQuery('.addwebcam').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('#cameraformwebcam').show();
    jQuery('#cameraformaxis').hide();
});

jQuery('.addaxiscam').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('#cameraformaxis').show();
    jQuery('#cameraformwebcam').hide();
});
```

Finally, my problem is the CSS code:

```
#AddCameraFormWebcam label,#AddCameraFormAxis label,
#AddCameraFormWebcam input,#AddCameraFormAxis input,
#AddCameraFormWebcam select,#AddCameraFormAxis select,
#AddCameraFormWebcam textarea,#AddCameraFormAxis textarea{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam select,#AddCameraFormAxis select{
  width: 100px;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam label,#AddCameraFormAxis label {
  clear: both;
  color: black;
  width: 120px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam label.error,#AddCameraFormAxis label.error {
  float: none;
  color: red;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[type="button"],#AddCameraFormAxis button[type="button"]{
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[type="submit"],#AddCameraFormAxis button[type="submit"] {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[name="cancel_changes"],#AddCameraFormAxis button[name="cancel_changes"] {
  clear: both;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[name="camera_status"] + label,#AddCameraFormAxis button[name="camera_status"] + label {
  clear: none;
}


.dropshadow-add {
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
 width:    400px;
 padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-right:15px;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 padding: 1px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6FwH/1/) to play around.

Click a button and you will see that form goes outside the div. How can I keep it in the div? If I change the buttons and the labels to `float: inherit` it does work but then the formatting is messed up. I want to put the form in the div and the buttons should be on the right (add button, then cancel button next to each other). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your **CSS** with this

```
#AddCameraFormWebcam label,#AddCameraFormAxis label, 
#AddCameraFormWebcam input,#AddCameraFormAxis input, 
#AddCameraFormWebcam select,#AddCameraFormAxis select, 
#AddCameraFormWebcam textarea,#AddCameraFormAxis textarea{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam select,#AddCameraFormAxis select{
    width: 100px;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam label,#AddCameraFormAxis label {
    clear: both;
    color: black;
    width: 120px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam label.error,#AddCameraFormAxis label.error {
    float: none;
    color: red;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[type="button"],#AddCameraFormAxis button[type="button"]{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[type="submit"],#AddCameraFormAxis button[type="submit"] {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[name="cancel_changes"],#AddCameraFormAxis button[name="cancel_changes"] {
    clear: both;
}
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[name="camera_status"] + label,#AddCameraFormAxis button[name="camera_status"] + label {
    clear: none;
}


.dropshadow-add {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #ccc;
  width:    400px;
  padding:15px 15px 15px 15px; 
  margin-bottom:15px;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-right:15px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 1px 15px 15px 15px;
}​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6FwH/2/

1.

```
#AddCameraFormWebcam label,#AddCameraFormAxis label,
#AddCameraFormWebcam input,#AddCameraFormAxis input,
#AddCameraFormWebcam select,#AddCameraFormAxis select,
#AddCameraFormWebcam textarea,#AddCameraFormAxis textarea{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

Remove **float: left;**

2.

```
#AddCameraFormWebcam button[type="button"],#AddCameraFormAxis button[type="button"]{
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Remove **float: right;** and **margin-left: 10px;**

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6FwH/2/**

If you want to keep the buttons right aligned

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/K6FwH/3/**

Comment: Thanks for looking but I'm trying to keep the buttons right aligned and next to each other.